# TextField returning nil with valid value entered. Parse.com Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a textfield that passes a value to a parse object.  It was working great, then I added a Tab Bar Controller to my TableViewController that is a subclass of PFQueryTableViewController. Now neither `self.message.text;` or `message.text`(synthesized) pass the correct value, instead it passes nil and my app crashes.

Here is a sample of the code I am trying to run:

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *echo = message.text;

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        PFObject *echoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Echo"];
        echoObject[@"body"] = echo;
        echoObject[@"title"] = @"Echo";
        echoObject[@"user"] = currentUser;
        [echoObject saveInBackground];

        NSLog(echo);
        NSLog(@"TEST");
    } else {
        // show the signup or login screen
    } 
    [self loadObjects];
    return YES;
}
```

Adding the TabBarController is the only thing I can think of that would effect the view controller in a way that breaks the code.  I will update the question if I think of anything else that could have broken the code.

I have verified that the object that causes the exception is `echoObject[@"body"] = echo;` due to the value being nil.  Also in the NSLog,  **message** does not get printed to console.

**UPDATE**

I managed to get the code to work by pulling the TextField value directly from the method, like so:

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *echo = textField.text;


    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        PFObject *echoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Echo"];
        echoObject[@"body"] = echo;
        echoObject[@"title"] = @"Echo";
        echoObject[@"user"] = currentUser;
        [echoObject saveInBackground];

        NSLog(echo);
        NSLog(@"TEST");
    } else {
        // show the signup or login screen
    }


    [self loadObjects];

    return YES;
}
```

This is how the code should have been in the first place, but I would like clarification on why the self pointer and the synthesized pointers were not working.

Comment: So `message` is nil? Show the code for how that's set. Check it exists at the beginning. You say the view controller change might be the cause but haven't really given any details about it...

Comment: Just in case, are you sure that `message` is a valid textfield? Try `textField.text` instead. `message` view *can't* be nil because it's triggering the delegate method.

Comment: how to print a uitextfield

Comment: Yes, message was nil when using self.message.text or message.text

Comment: Britton, sorry `message` is supposed to be `echo` doesn't solve initial problem though.

Comment: sonxurxo, seems to have solved the crash.  But i'm still wondering why I was unable to access the value the way I was doing.